# How do i remove rtl8723de modules using dkms

Tags: 16.04, drivers, apt, kernel, dpkg

```
nishanthr@vision:~$ dkms status
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.15.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414, 4.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414, 4.13.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414, 4.13.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.6: added
```

I want to remove all the rtl8723de modules to reinstall them.
Which command should be used with dkms remove with respect to my module and version I want to remove.

I also tried this:

```
nishanthr@vision:~$ sudo dkms uninstall -m 4.13.0-37-generic rtl8723de
[sudo] password for nishanthr: 
Error! Invalid number of arguments passed.
Usage: uninstall <module>/<module-version> or
       uninstall -m <module>/<module-version> or
       uninstall -m <module> -v <module-version>
```

Comment: You are missing `-v` in your command. `sudo dkms uninstall -m 4.13.0-37-generic -v rtl8723de` Oh and I would assume -m module to be rtl8723de and not the kernel. So `sudo dkms uninstall -m rtl8723de` and `5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414` seems the version to me(?) Please try that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
sudo dkms remove rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 --all
sudo depmod -a
```

Reboot and check:

```
sudo dkms status
```

Comment: The version number (may) be incorrect. Do `ls -al /usr/src` to determine if they used the full version number, or just 5.1.1.8_21285 or 5.1.1.8 or something in between.